# Javascript to replace text in Gmail message (Chrome Extension)

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to write a Chrome Extension which will replace a string of text in Gmail messages.

If I open a Gmail message and click the print button to see it in print view and run the extension it works well and replaces all instances of the string.

However, if I run the extension in the normal Gmail discussion view it causes the page to refresh and it does not actually replace any of the text.

Here is the code I'm using. Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
function doIt(){
findAndReplace("Father","Mother");
}

var haystackText = "";
function findAndReplace(needle, replacement) {
 if (haystackText.length == 0) {
      haystackText = document.body.innerHTML;
 }

 var match = new RegExp(needle, "ig");     
 var replaced = "";
 if (replacement.length > 0) {
      replaced = haystackText.replace(match, replacement);         
      document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
 }

}

doIt();
```

**Update:**
Here is the updated code I'm using after Felix Kling's help. Similar issue to the one above, it works in print preview but not in the regular Gmail view. It does not however reload the page.

```
function findAndReplace(root, needle, replacement) {
    var children = root.childNodes;
    var pattern = new RegExp(needle, 'ig');
    var node;
    for(var i = 0, l = children.length; i < l; i++) {
        node = children[i];
        if(node.nodeType === 3) { // we have a text node
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacement);
        } else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // Element node
            findAndReplace(node, needle, replacement);
        }
    }
}

function doIt(){
  findAndReplace(document,"Father","Mother");
}

doIt();
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are changing the whole document. You are basically destroying and creating every element of the page.

```
document.body.innerHTML = replaced;
```

inserts every element of the page anew, so all JavaScript code is executed again etc.

You should only change those text nodes that contain the text you are looking for. That means you have to recursively traverse the DOM (not the whole, start at the message list), test the node type and value and perform the necessary actions.

**Update:** Example

```
function findAndReplace(root, needle, replacement) {
    var children = root.childNodes,
        pattern = new RegExp(needle, 'ig');
        node;

    for(var i = 0, l = childNodes.length; i < l; i++) {
        node = children[i];
        if(node.nodeType === 3) { // we have a text node
            node.nodeValue = node.nodeValue.replace(pattern, replacement);
        } else if(node.nodeType === 1) { // Element node
            findAndReplace(node, needle, replacement);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a simple example. I actually don't know how well it performs, but I think you have no other choice. Further things to consider are e.g. escaping special regular expressions characters in the search string.

To learn more about JavaScript and DOM, I recommend to read:

- [MDN - JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide)
- [MDN - DOM reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Gecko_DOM_Reference) (espcially the introduction)

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you. I'm new to javascript and am trying to find an example of text replacement by traversing the DOM. Are you able to recommend an example (or suggest what I should be googling as I can not seem to find anything).

Comment: @user: I provided a simple example.

Comment: Thanks, I took the example and had a play with it. Unfortunately I am still having the same problem. When I run the script on the Gmail print preview it will work correctly. However when I run it in the normal Gmail window, it will do nothing (at least it doesn't reset the page anymore) but it doesn't update any of the text. Code to follow...

Comment: I had a typo in the script, but then it should not even work in the print view...

Comment: Sorry, new to stack overflow. I've put the updated code in my first post.

I noticed the typos and fixed them up. As I said though, it works well in the print preview mode now, just it doesn't work in the normal Gmail page :(

Comment: @user: Try it with `document.body` instead of `document`. *edit:* but I guess it should still work.... it could be that your extension is running before the messages are loaded?

Comment: I tried with document.body. Same result in both the print preview and Gmail view. However, one difference was that if the title contains the text to be replaced, it will update the title in Gmail.

I added some debugging information, when running in Gmail view it never replaces the text. So I don't think it is falling into the if statement for whatever reason? I placed a debug comment to show me if the nodevalue changed.

Comment: I honestly don't know what to do else (and I don't have any time right now). Keep trying somehow and keep me updated...

Comment: Will do. Thanks for your help. I'm debugging and can see that in Gmail the email body text mustn't be a text node as it is never seen within that if statement.

Comment: @user: Every text in the DOM must eventually be in a text node. I suggest you inspect the DOM element that contains the text. Good luck!

Comment: Looking some more into it. It appears that Gmail somehow hides the e-mail contents from the INNERHTML somehow. I've read of other people finding this. Haven't found a way around it though :(

Comment: @user: Interesting.... I'm sorry that I'm really short of time, but if I have some more, I will investigate on this. Sorry that I cannot help you immediately...

Comment: That's alright, I appreciate the help you provided. Thanks for trying.